# target element in click event in nested divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two nested divs

```
<div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to implement a modal dialog effect. My CSS and jQuery works fine in showing the modal dialog.

When I try to hide the modal dialog with the following jQuery.

```
$(".modal-container").click(function (event) {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

It hides the modal-container but the problem is it hides it even when I click on modal-content div. What I want to achieve is the regular modal effect that allows to click inside content without dismissing the modal dialog but when clicked on the grayed area (outside the inner content div) it should dismiss the dialog.

How can we achieve it without using the id's of the divs as I have multiple content divs, and I want to work it with the class selectors.

Comment: Are you sure that there is not another dom element to click? usually that `gray` area its an overlay div. You an add the click event to that overlay....

Comment: Although what you are asking for can be done, why are you not using a jquery plugin for modals? since they all have this effect and much more built-in

Comment: @David. That entirely relies on the overlay div not being bart pf the div nesting as it is in his case. Otherwise the event will still propagate through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click event is bubbling up to the container which hides the modal. [Read about it here](https://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing).

On content click prevent click event to propagate

```
$(".modal-content").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

More info on [stopPrapagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `event.target` to check if the clicked element is the `.modal-container`

```
$(".modal-container").click(function (event) {
    if(event.target == this){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

But since you're already using jQuery, I recommend using a modal plugin, since they have this functionality and many others built-in (there are tons you can find for free)

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
$(".modal-container").click(function (event) {
    $(event.target).hide()

});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!